Open multiple folders using a batch script, but open them in one window in multiple tabs
I need a code to open multiple folders in one click using a bat file and open them only in ONE window, displayed in multiple tabs.
I found a code where it can open multiple folder in one click using a batch file, but the code works only to open them in multiple windows. Below is the code:
@echo off
start explorer "Folder 1 Path"
start explorer "Folder 2 Path"
start explorer "Folder 3 Path"
start explorer "Folder 4 Path"

The code above works, but all folders open on its own separate windows.
The code came from this question:
How to open multiple folders in a specific order using batch file? Windows 10
Instead i want all folders to open only ONE window and in multiple tabs, since windows 11 features opening multiple folders at the same time in one window.
The setting in my folder options, General>Browse folder>Open each folder in the same window is already checked.
There are third party utilities that forces opening folders in same window but my organization does not allow installing third party apps.

The answer in how to open new tab with command line in file explorer? says that as of November 2022 it wasn't supported. I haven't yet found anything which says it is now supported.

You may need to specify the /wait parameter for start, to specify that you want each command to wait for completion before it goes to the next, so you can actually allow explorer to spawn.

Are you using Windows 11? Use winver.exe to add version and build to question.
